# Parsing value of PHP array to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, key

I am coding on a page which calculates a price dynamically when changing the input field :

```
<input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" type="number" value="0" min="1" max="6">
```

The calculation is base on a php array:

```
$plz[01] = array( 1=> 58, 2=> 43, 3=> 32, 4=> 26, 5=> 22, 6=> 19 );
$plz[02] = array( 1=> 58, 2=> 43, 3=> 32, 4=> 26, 5=> 22, 6=> 19 );
$plz[03] = array( 1=> 58, 2=> 43, 3=> 32, 4=> 26, 5=> 22, 6=> 19 );
```

Im trying to parse PHP code to my script and this works:

```
$("#amount").on('change',function() {
var sum = <?php echo $plz[01][6]; ?>;
}
```

But I need the value of the selected amount as key. Something like this:

```
$("#amount").on('change',function() {
var sum = <?php echo $plz[01] [$(this).val();] ?>;
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not export the PHP arrays to JavaScript using `json_encode`? Also note that using `01` will become base-8, instead of what you expected it to be (like "01")

Comment: I think you meant "pass" instead of "parse"/"parsing".

Comment: you can save values in to js var before or create extra php file and hold values from that via $.ajax load function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `json_encode` in your PHP code to output the array in JSON to your JS code which you can then parse to an object.

```
var json = <?= json_encode($plz) ?>;
var arr = JSON.parse(json);
```

From there you can read the array as required:

```
$("#amount").on('change', function() {
    var sum = arr['01'][this.value - 1];
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/jf4stfgf/)

Note in the example above I included the JSON directly, but that is what should be output from PHP given your sample array.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try with JSON.

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped, you can accept it by clicking the green tick to the left